# Create GameObjects the have gravity based on size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gravity

I've built a fractal based object generator in c# and unity that builds branches of objects that then bounce off each other using Colliders and Rigidbodies. Right now they hit each other and keep moving farther and farther apart. What I'd like to do it assign each object a certain level of gravitational attraction so that even as they're repelled through a collision they draw themselves back in. I've got everything except working except for the gravity side of things. Does anyone have experience with this who wouldn't mind giving me some direction? Thanks!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class BuildFractal : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Mesh[] meshes;
    public Material material;
    public Material[,] materials;
    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    public int maxDepth;             // max children depth
    private int depth;
    public float childScale;         // set scale of child objects
    public float spawnProbability;   // determine whether a branch is created or not
    public float maxRotationSpeed;   // set maximium rotation speed
    private float rotationSpeed;
    public float maxTwist;
    public Text positionText;

    // Create arrays for direction and orientation data
    private static Vector3[] childDirections = {
        Vector3.up,
        Vector3.right,
        Vector3.left,
        Vector3.forward,
        Vector3.back,
        // Vector3.down
    };
    private static Quaternion[] childOrientations = {
        Quaternion.identity,
        Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, -90f),
        Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 90f),
        Quaternion.Euler(90f, 0f, 0f),
        Quaternion.Euler(-90f, 0f, 0f),
        // Quaternion.Euler(180f, 0f, 0f)
    };

    private void Start () 
    {
        rotationSpeed = Random.Range(-maxRotationSpeed, maxRotationSpeed);
        transform.Rotate(Random.Range(-maxTwist, maxTwist), 0f, 0f);

        if (materials == null)
        {
            InitializeMaterials();
        }

        // Select from random range of meshes
        gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = meshes[Random.Range(0, meshes.Length)];
        // Select from random range of colors
        gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = materials[depth, Random.Range(0, 2)];
        // Add a collider to each object
        gameObject.AddComponent<SphereCollider>().isTrigger = false;
        // Add Rigigbody to each object
        gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass = 1000;

        // Create Fractal Children
        if (depth < maxDepth)
        {
            StartCoroutine(CreateChildren());
        }
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0f, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
    }

    private IEnumerator CreateChildren ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < childDirections.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Random.value < spawnProbability)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0.1f, 1.5f));
                new GameObject("Fractal Child").AddComponent<BuildFractal>().Initialize(this, i);
            }

            /*if (i == childDirections.Length)
            {
                DestroyChildren();
            }*/

            // positionText.text = transform.position.ToString(this);
        }
    }

    private void Initialize (BuildFractal parent, int childIndex)
    {
        maxRotationSpeed = parent.maxRotationSpeed;

        // copy mesh and material references from parent object
        meshes = parent.meshes;
        materials = parent.materials;
        maxTwist = parent.maxTwist;

        // set depth and scale based on variables defined in parent
        maxDepth = parent.maxDepth;
        depth = parent.depth + 1;
        childScale = parent.childScale;

        transform.parent = parent.transform;           // set child transform to parent

        // transform.localScale = Vector3.one * childScale;


        transform.localScale = Vector3.one * Random.Range(childScale / 10, childScale * 1);
        transform.localPosition = childDirections[childIndex] * (Random.Range((0.1f + 0.1f * childScale),(0.9f + 0.9f * childScale)));
        transform.localRotation = childOrientations[childIndex];

        spawnProbability = parent.spawnProbability;
    }

    private void InitializeMaterials ()
    {
        materials = new Material[maxDepth + 1, 2];

        for (int i = 0; i <= maxDepth; i++)
        {
            float t = i / (maxDepth - 1f);
            t *= t;

            // Create a 2D array to hold color progressions
            materials[i, 0] = new Material(material);
            materials[i, 0].color = Color.Lerp(Color.gray, Color.white, t);
            materials[i, 1] = new Material(material);
            materials[i, 1].color = Color.Lerp(Color.white, Color.white, t);
        }
        // materials[maxDepth, 0].color = Color.white;
        materials[maxDepth, 1].color = Color.white;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, there's a game development stack exchange site [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how accurate your gravity simulation has to be. Assuming all objects in your simulation have the same density, you could use Mesh.bounds to roughly estimate their volume:

```
Vector3 size = myMesh.bounds.size;
float volume =  size.x * size.y * size.z * scale;    // scale could be childScale in your case
```

Since your simulation is a fractal, you will have to apply childScale in each of your fractal's iterations. But you don't have to recalculate the base volume of your mesh if it doesn't change.

As for the gravity simulation:
This might get quite complex with a high number of objects. You would have to simulate a whole gravity field.

The calculation for only two objects interacting with each other is rather simple. The forces applied to the bodies attracting each other can be calculated by the Newtonian formula

> F1 = F2 = G * m1 * m2 / r^2

(see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant)

But you may have far more objects than two in your system. You would have to calculate the above relationship for each object -- between each object. And for each object, you would have to add all calculated forces and than apply the resulting force.

Let's say you have N objects in your scene, you would have to do (N-1) of the above calculations for each object. That yields N^(N-1) calculations, which will get out of hand quite quickly, especially if you doing it in a fractal structure.

To get hold of this immense complexity, you could introduce a range of influence, so only nearby objects have an effect on each other. Although this will further reduce the accuracy of your simulation.